# EF Core 2 - how to call scalar function?

Tags: linq, user-defined-functions, ef-core-2.0, scalar

I am using EF Core 2.

I have a user-defined function in my SQL.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION udfCPIAdjustedAmount
(
    @WorkOrderID int,
    @VendorContractPayItemID int,
    @Qty decimal,
    @QtyIdle decimal,
    @QtyOT decimal
)
RETURNS decimal(18,2)
AS
BEGIN
-- code replaced with something simple
    return @Qty * 2

END
```

It is declared in my DbContext class like this:

```
[DbFunction("udfCPIAdjustedAmount", "dbo")]
    public static decimal CPIAdjustedAmount(int WorkOrderID, int VendorContractPayItemid, decimal Qty, decimal QtyIdle, decimal QtyOT) { throw new Exception(); }
```

I am able to call it successfully from my controller like this:

```
decimal AdjustedAmount = (from wo in _context.WorkOrder
                                       where wo.WorkOrderID == WorkOrderID
                                       select PMSContext.CPIAdjustedAmount(WorkOrderID, VendorContractPayItemID, Qty, QtyIdle, QtyOT)).First();
```

However, I feel like there must be a simpler way. I can see no reason to have to reference any specific table in the LINQ query (e.g. the WorkOrder table in the example I gave). It returns a decimal value and the parameters to the UDF do not refer to any query data.

I feel like I should be able to do something like this:

```
decimal AdjustedAmount = PMSContext.CPIAdjustedAmount(WorkOrderID, VendorContractPayItemID, Qty, QtyIdle, QtyOT);
```

But that just throws an exception.

Any suggestions?

TIA!

Comment: I think the easiest would be to define view which use this function then you can query that view.

Comment: CPIAdjustAmount seems to me a standard static function within your DbContext. Just out of curiosity: this function throws an Exception. Is that the Exception you get? Do you also get an exception if the procedure just would `return 7;`, and you tried: `decimal adjustedAmount = PMSContext.CPIAdjustedAmount(...)`

Comment: @Harald Coppoolse, the code I posted, that matches what you posted, returns the Exception that is thrown from the public static function that I posted. I am quite confident that if I changed that function to "return 7;", that is what it would return. But, that is not helpful.

I could change that function to do the LINQ query instead, but that doesn't solve the problem. It just moves the code I don't like from one place to another.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I am not following you. I could create a View, but then my LINQ query would look exactly the same, only referring to a View, instead of a table, correct? To me, that is not any different.

Answer (score 1):

**DbFunction** enables mapping database scalar functions to a method in the class.

This method can only be used in LINQ queries and is translated into a SQL Statement. PMSContext in the below statement will translated it into a SQL statement so this will work as expected.

```
decimal AdjustedAmount = (from wo in _context.WorkOrder
                                       where wo.WorkOrderID == WorkOrderID
                                       select PMSContext.CPIAdjustedAmount(WorkOrderID, VendorContractPayItemID, Qty, QtyIdle, QtyOT)).First();
```

In the below statement the method is used without the DbContext object and not inside a LINQ query, so it will execute as a C# statement not as a SQL query so it will throw the Exception that is thrown from the method.

```
decimal AdjustedAmount = PMSContext.CPIAdjustedAmount(WorkOrderID, VendorContractPayItemID, Qty, QtyIdle, QtyOT);
```